# JSX expressions must have one parent element.ts(2657) react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native and have tried everything and keep getting the following error

> JSX expressions must have one parent element.ts(2657)

I am trying to display information from json in a flatlist.

Here is my code.

```js
render() {
  if (this.state.isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
      </View>
    );
  }
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#808080' }}>
        <Text style={styles.MainText}>Sermons</Text>
      </View>
      <FlatList style={{ paddingTop: 30 }}
        data={DATA}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
        renderItem={this._renderItem} />
    </View>
  );
}

_renderItem = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', paddingLeft: 10 }}>
        <Image source={require('./church.png')} style={{ width: '100%', height: '25%' }} />
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingLeft: 20 }}>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}
```

line 33 ); seems to be causing the problem but I don't know why.

Comment: The last `return` has two `<View>`s directly inside it. It has to return a single component/element that contains everything below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a container `View`:

```js
_renderItem = ({item}) => {

  return(
<View>
    <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row', paddingLeft: 10}}>
       <Image source={require('./church.png')} style={{width: '100%', height: '25%'}} />
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingLeft: 20}}>
          <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      </View>
 </View>

  );
}
```

Comment: You are welcome, if the answer help you please accept it or add +1.Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can't render adjacent elements. They must have a single parent element. [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) is a common solution for this:

```
return(
  <>
    <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row', paddingLeft: 10}}>
      <Image source={require('./church.png')} style={{width: '100%', height: '25%'}} />
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: 1, paddingLeft: 20}}>
      <Text>{item.title}</Text>
    </View>
  </>
);
```

`<></>` is short for `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>`.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 view components in return. You should have 1 parent component so you can wrap them into a react fragment.

```
  return(
   <>
     <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row', paddingLeft: 10}}>
       <Image source={require('./church.png')} style={{width: '100%', height: '25%'}} />
     </View>
     <View style={{flex: 1, paddingLeft: 20}}>
          <Text>{item.title}</Text>
     </View>
   </>

  );
```